# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dynamics-gp

Under the references for the class library I changed the removed the old version of dll and added the new dll. When ever my business logic library tries to create an object to this library it gives me the following error:

```cs
 eConnect = new EConnectIntegrationGroup(cnString);
```

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040

Comment: Is that class deprecated in the new version?

Comment: What is the version of new dll?

Comment: The dll which is being referenced in the library has changes the class library using it does not change

Comment: Can't get you. you mean you refer 'Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization' dll in many projects rite?

Answer (score 0):

your business logic is still looking for the dll with version 12.0.0.0. Is this the only place where the dll is used or do other projects also have this dll added to references?

Comment: This should be a comment, this is not an answer

Comment: I could not add a comment since the minimum reputation should be 50. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that's actually annoying when we try to help someone but we can't

Comment: I also suspect the same

Comment: the project or its dependencies are still looking for the old version file. You need to figure out which other project is pointing to the older version and change that reference to the newer ones.